# Garafa's GPS kit offline capability for Google Maps API

Tags: google-maps, caching, gps, gis, bing-maps

I have read time and again here on SO that it is not possible/permitted to cache google maps in a third party app. Some of the questions which have this answer are:

[offline google map with gps for android](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14549180/2598660)

[Offline use of google maps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16120290/2598660)

[is it possible to cache map for offline use in a way other than saving tiled images?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19350146/2598660)

However I was using the [GPS Kit](http://garafa.com/wordpress/all-apps/gps-kit) by Garafa on my iPhone, and it has the capability to cache map tiles specified by the user by drawing a rectangular,circular or free hand region by finger on the map. The type of maps supported for caching are:

Google Terrain

Google Cycling

Google Satellite

Google Street

Bing Shaded Relief

Bing Street

Bing Image

Google Hybrid

Open Street

Open Topo

the main question is that how is it possible for Garafa to cache google maps in their app if the google API doesnot support caching tiles for offline use. Do we have to buy a license from Bing or Google in order to cache tiles in the app on the go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a question that comes up often. Even asking google about it comes back with some inconsistant answers. It basically breaks down like this. You cannot locally cache or save data from google that is obtained or provided for by the Google Maps API.

You can cache and save (with conditions) Maps optained through the Google Maps Static API. It doesn't have as rich functionality as the normal Google maps api but it does work quite well once you work out how to convert it to be used on other maps.